# How to add an image to the redmine top menu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins

I want to put an image on the top menu of my redmine plugin index page.

In init.rb

menu :top_menu, :my_link, {:controller => 'my_controller', :action => 'my_action'},
       :caption => "My title" 
where could a link to any image fit in this syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do it with css.

If you create a menu with:

```
menu :top_menu, :my_link, {:controller => 'my_controller', :action => 'my_action'}, :caption => "My title"
```

It will be created with the class 'my-link'.

All you have to do is to define on your css:

```
#top-menu a.my-link {     
  padding-left: 20px;
  background-image: url(../images/my-link.png); 
}
```